# Ruby on rails tutorial : route_url and HTML - I am stock

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, rubygems

I am a total novice (Please read my profile) and started following a Ruby on Rails tutorial but am stock half way.

The tutorial is here

http://12devs.co.uk/articles/writing-a-web-application-with-ruby-on-rails/

Halfway the page, it started introducing devise gem. Which I installed without a problem.

I followed the instructions up to 
"Devise also told us to check five steps to complete the setup:"

I don't understand what to do / where to add the following steps

1)define a root_url in config/routes.rb. Fow now, we can achieve this by pointing BookmarksController#index to the root of the site:

Bookmarks::Application.routes.draw do # [...] root ‘bookmarks#index’

## [...] end

!What code do I exactly put inside the routes.rb file? and where? 
I have copy pasted the above in a random location in the file but I am aware this is not the write code. As there are comments and there is meant to be something instead on [...]
PLEASE HELP

2)add the two pieces of html in app/views/layouts/application.html.erb. This file is the main layout your Rails app.

!Where are the HTML codes I need to enter? And what is that code? I cannot find any codes to insert

Your help is really really appreciated.

Thank you
Sam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Open `config/routes.rb` and add `root :to => "bookmarks#index"`

**config/routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root :to => "bookmarks#index"
end
```

2. Add the two pieces of html in `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb`

**app/views/layouts/application.html.erb**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Beautify</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>
<!-- two pieces -->
<p class="notice"><%= notice %></p>
<p class="alert"><%= alert %></p>
<!-- end two pieces -->

<%= yield %>

</body>
</html>
```

:)

Comment: Thank you so so much! Sorry for dumb questions! :)

Comment: more newbie questions to be asked soon haha ;)

Comment: Thank you. I have posted a Part 2, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33811214/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-part-two-im-stock-on   If you had time, I would appreciate a feedback, Only if you had time for it ! :) I really have no idea what I'm doing. Thanks

Comment: @kalelc Thanks for the answer! I had the same problem. I was wondering how you knew which two pieces of html to add? (nevermind I should read better) In this tutorial the terminal response gives you the html tags