# Ruby on Rails tutorial part two

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, rubygems

I keep getting stock [sic] in a RoR tutorial. Part 1 is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33809022). After doing that, I ran the command:

```
rails generate devise User
```

Not sure if that is the correct code to type as the tutorial is not clear.
I'm not sure what the command does, and which files are connected to what etc. I get an error:

```
/home/sam/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:260:in `block (2 levels) in check_controller_and_action': 'BookmarksController' is not a supported controller name. This can lead to potential routing problems. See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#specifying-a-controller-to-use (ArgumentError)
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: do you have `app/controllers/bookmarks_controller.rb` ?

Comment: Already have the bookmarks_controller file which was generated automatically, Any other suggestions?

Comment: look at my updated answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the following from

`root :to => "BookmarksController#index"`

to this

`root :to => "bookmarks#index"`

Look at these tutorials

1. http://tryruby.org/
2. http://railsforzombies.org/

Comment: Already have the bookmarks_controller file which was generated automatically, Any other suggestions?

Comment: @kalelc thank you it worked. But now I've got new problems... Why am I getting errors in almost all steps even though I follow the exact instructions?

Comment: Please check the tutorials that put you on the answer. The problem is you need to understand concepts that apparently in the tutorial you're looking at overlook. :)